# DatabaseCleaner with Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, resque

Got a weird problem that I can't find addressed anywhere.

I'm using [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) in a project along with [DatabaseCleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) to clean up between tests. Our test suite needs to actually use regular resque/redis (so we can't use the monkeypatching ResqueSpec as it bypassess Resque/Redis usage).

We've been trying to use DBCleaner's `:transaction` strategy, but because Resque spawns out its own ActiveRecord connection after_fork (see code below), the transactions won't work as mysql only allows transactions to be seen on a single connection.

Resque does this:

```
Resque.after_fork { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection if defined?(ActiveRecord) }
```

The easy solution is to use DB cleaner with the `:truncation` strategy. We'd like to be able to switch on `:truncation` only when using Resque and then back over to `:transaction` when running unrelated specs.

Part of the trick is that our Resque worker is up and running for the duration of the specs. It starts up a worker when the test specs startup and then simply suspends the worker process after the `@resque`-marked spec is done running via a set of `Before`/`After` hooks.

So the question is how do we get DatabaseCleaner to effectively switch all active ActiveRecord DB connections to use the right cleaning strategy? DatabaseCleaner provides methods of switching strategies for different specs, but it doesn't seem to make the switch to all connections, rather only to the main Rails-process AR connection.

Again, solution for now is to use `:truncation` everywhere. Just wanted to know if anyone had any thoughts on how to work around this.

Comment: I use postgresql, seems that truncation is really slow.  :(  Also, any ACID-compliant database shouldn't let other connections see what's in an uncommitted transacation -- so I don't think that's mysql specific.  I think that's your problem, using the transaction feature of DatabaseCleaner means that other processes won't see any data inserted into the database until the transaction is completed, which will never happen (as the transaction is rolled back).